# Laravel Blade template Stack is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am developing a web application using Laravel. What I am doing now is rendering the content using the Blade stack feature as mentioned here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks. The problem is it is not working. See my simple code below.

This is my view content

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@stack('stack_content')

   <h1>Other contents</h1>

@prepend('stack_content')
      <h1>This is my name</h1>
@endprepend


@section('content')

@endsection
```

How it is not working is that it is not displaying this content

```
<h1>This is my name</h1>
```

at all. Not only stack area, but also in the original area as well. What is wrong?

Comment: which version of laravel do you use? I think 'prepend' whas implemented in 5.6, otherwise use 'push'

Comment: Latest version. 5.7

Comment: I used push as well. Simply not working

Comment: Are stack and prepend/push in the same template?  I don't think that will work.  "push to named stacks which can be rendered **somewhere else in another view or layout**"

Comment: as @Devon said, I don't see the problem when 'stack' is in a different file.

Comment: It is not working when I put it in another view as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stacks should be used in layouts.  There are not many reasons, if any, to put a stack in the same blade template.

In the example in the docs, the stack is defined in the layout's `<head>`.  The template that extends that layout is where you would push or prepend the code to that stack.  (Although the docs could be more clear about this)

The blade view's sections are rendered and then placed into the extended layout in the appropriate places, which is what makes it possible to define where content is loaded.

You can't define a section with yield and then define the content inside that section.  As soon as the layout hits @yield or @stack, it's going to render what has been defined in that section.

In other words, this works because the section content is rendered before it hits yield:

```
            @section('test')
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            @endsection
            @yield('test')
```

But this won't:

```
            @yield('test')
            @section('test')
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            @endsection
```

The same logical order applies to stacks.

Comment: Got it. Very well explained. Cheers. mate.